# DIV width in % and padding

Tags: html, css

I have 2 DIVs next to each other (A to the left and B to the right) within a container of 980px wide. I set a width of 50% for both A and B which works great.

Question: I'd like to add some padding-right to DIV A so that the text in it doesn't touch the  text of div B. If I do that I need to adjust the % of the DIV (i.e. to 48%). Is there a way to avoid that? (i.e. get the % automatically adjusted based on the padding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, you can use the `box-sizing` property. By setting:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

The width property will set the total width (including borders and padding), so for example a div with:

```
div {
    width:500px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 10px solid blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

would have a visual overall width of 500px, rather than a default width of 500 + 40 + 20 = 560px.

For reference: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `box-sizing:border-box` to the `div`s with padding.

```
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

[**Live demo**](http://jsbin.com/AcipeMI/1/edit)

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

> `border-box`:
>   The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin.

`box-sizing` is supported all the way back to IE8.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using one more wrapping `div`:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
         <div class="left"></div>
         <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.wrapper { width: 960px; }
.inner { padding: 1em; }
.left, .right { width: 50%; float: left; }
```

Or use `box-sizing` that makes calulations very easy.

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

It changes the rendering of paddings and border so that they are included in the width rather than added to it.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to add padding without reducing the width of the div, you can use: `box-sizing: border-box;` [More info](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

e.g.

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

This will make your div the desired width (50%), and the padding will be subtracted rather than added to the div. Beware this is a CSS3 property and won't work in all versions of IE:
http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
<div class="tbl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">A</div>
    <div class="cell">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tbl{

  display:table;
  border-spacing:5px;
}
.row{
  display:table-row;

}
.cell{
  display:table-cell;
  width:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

for width, margin & padding values use % or em values

Have a look at this code

```
 .container { 
     max-width: 980px;
 }
 section {
     float: left;
     margin: 0.0122448;   /*  10px ÷ 980px */
     width: 0.479591;   /* 470px ÷ 660px  */   
 }
 aside {
     float: right;
     margin: 0.0122448;   /*  10px ÷ 980px */
     width: 0.479591;   /* 470px ÷ 980px */
}
```

for complete tutorial on responsive design -

http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/responsive-web-design

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `box-sizing:border-box;`
 beacuse using `border-box;` will give you a look of box with border & it will manage space for border by itself .
 you can give width and color of your border by yourself `border:2px solid black;` . And thus, the content of your both divs can be diffrentiated.